# Calculate Average Days Between Events (Cannot Aggregate b/c Used Windowed Function)

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, aggregate

I'm trying to find the average & median days between two events, grouped by Unitcode. I've got the days between two events for one particular unit.

```
SELECT 
    uni_int_UnitId AS UnitID, 
    uty_vch_Code AS UnitCode, 
    uty_int_Id AS UnitID,  tul_int_FacilityId AS FacilityID, 
    CONVERT(DATE, tul_dtm_MoveInDate) AS Move_In_Date, 
    CONVERT(DATE, tul_dtm_MoveOutDate) AS Move_Out_Date, 
    DATEDIFF(day, tul_dtm_MoveInDate, tul_dtm_MoveOutDate) AS Occupancy_Days,
    CONVERT(DATE, LAG(tul_dtm_MoveOutDate) over (partition by uni_int_UnitId order by tul_dtm_MoveOutDate)) AS Previous_Move_Out_Date,
    DATEDIFF(day,LAG(tul_dtm_MoveOutDate, 1) over (partition by uni_int_UnitId order by tul_dtm_MoveInDate),tul_dtm_MoveInDate) as Days_Vacant

FROM TenantUnitLeases
JOIN units
    ON tul_int_UnitId = uni_int_UnitId
JOIN UnitTypes
    ON uni_int_UnitTypeId = uty_int_Id
WHERE   tul_int_UnitId = '27969'
ORDER BY tul_dtm_MoveInDate ASC
```

Now I want to run a query but for thousands of units and come up with an average and median by UnitCode (a way to group Units).

Because I used the Windowed Function LAG, I cannot aggregate by UnitCode.  I feel like an additional OVER (PARTITION BY...) may get me there, but can't quite figure it out.

Also I need to figure out how to eliminate the first row for each unitID b/c it will always be null.  Because I'm calculating days vacant, there is no previous move out date to calculate days vacant.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you considered a subquery?

Comment: As per the question guide, please DO NOT post images of code, data, error messages, etc. - copy or type the text into the question. Please reserve the use of images for diagrams or demonstrating rendering bugs, things that are impossible to describe accurately via text.

Comment: @DaleK removed images.  New to SO, so getting the hang of the rules. Thanks.

Comment: @GordonLinoff will give that some thought, thank you.